alternate law of tangents?
In the response to a related question here is given a formula to compute one of the angles not given for an SAS triangle:
$$\tan(A) = \frac{\sin(C)}{\frac{b}{a}-\cos(C)}$$
where $a,b,C$ are the given sides and angle, and $A$ (or $A+\pi$ when $tan(A)<0$) is the angle opposite of side $a$.
Is there a name for this formula? It is similar to the law of tangents (also referenced there) as a method to compute an angle from the given sides and angle without needing to calculate the length of the 3rd side first. A difference is that this formula can generate a negative angle instead of an obtuse angle (in which case it indicates that one must add $\pi$). Here, I refer to it as the "tangent law" as distinguished from the "law of tangents".

Wouldn't that allow us to know that A=90°?

Yes. And the angle you calculate will be off as demonstrated at the end of the answer here.

Gwen, thinking more about this and having edited the answer, your comment may not make sense without context. If $b/a\approx\cos(C)$ then the angle we are computing is almost in a right triangle. This can happen for an isosceles triangle with a very small angle or for an arbitrarily shaped right triangle. In case of the former $A$ is just $(180^o-C)/2$. And in case of the latter we can calculate angle $B$, replacing $b/a$ with $a/b$ and removing the condition of near cancellation, but I haven't convinced myself whether this needs to be done.

This equation may be obtained by replacing $A+B$ in the tangent law with $\pi - C$ and then expanding the tangents of sums, solving for $tan(A)$ and rewriting $tan(C)$ as $sin(C)/cos(C)$ on the rhs (and simplifying). e.g. here is a demonstration using SymPy:
>>> from sympy.abc import *
>>> from sympy import *
>>> lot = (a - b)/(a + b) - tan(A/2 - B/2)/tan(A/2 + B/2)
>>> solve(lot.subs(B,pi-A-C).expand(trig=True).rewrite(tan),tan(A))
[2*a*tan(C/2)/(a*tan(C/2)**2 - a + b*tan(C/2)**2 + b)]
>>> _[0].rewrite(cos)
2*a*cos(C/2 - pi/2)/((-a + a*cos(C/2 - pi/2)**2/cos(C/2)**2 + b + b*cos(C/2 - pi/2)**2/cos(C/2)**2)*cos(C/2))
>>> expand(_,trig=True).simplify()
a*sin(C)/(-a*cos(C) + b)
>>> (numer(_)/a)/expand(denom(_)/a)
sin(C)/(-cos(C) + b/a)  <--- the equation presented in the OP

The OP is not a new equation, per se, just a re-arrangement of the law of tangents to make it more tractable. It can also be derived from the law of sines by an easier derivation as demonstrated here.
